# S3 Uploading Excel File and Downloading it via SignedURL

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to upload an excel file into S3 and download it via a signedURL. What I've noticed is that the object comes back in a different file-type instead of the expected xlsx type, and thus is unreadable locally.

I have two lambdas, one for uploading the object and another for retrieving the signedURL.

Upload:

```
async function () => {
  const s3 = new aws.S3({ signatureVersion: 'v4' })
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key
  }

  try {
    const signedURL = await s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params)
    return response(200, signedURL)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
    return response(400, err)
  }
}
```

GetSignedURL:

```
async function () => {
  const s3 = new aws.S3({ signatureVersion: 'v4' })
  const params = {
     Bucket: bucket,
     Key: key
  }

  try {
     const signedURL = await s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params)
     return response(200, { signedURL, key })
  } catch (err) {
    return response(400, err)
  }
}
```

I'm guessing that the file doesn't actually get saved with its original file-type and S3 actually just converts it to text-file. Maybe I need an additional parameter or package to explicitly save it as an Excel file. Please let me know your thoughts!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the ContentType in params. Im not sure if this one is the right one for excel but providing the correct content type should address the issue. I had a similar issue when uploading images. I forgot to set the ContentType to image/jpeg

```
const params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key,
    ContentType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
  }
```

> ```
> Other possible options 
> "xls"       => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
> "xlsx"      => "vnd.ms-excel",
> ```

Comment: Gonna give this a try! :D

Comment: Would we have to specify the ContentType in both the upload and retriever?

Comment: I think you can override response headers if needed.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property

Comment: Freaking brilliant. Thank you sir.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer! I was just wondering if you happen to know why only xls files seem to be accepted. I tried the last option `vnd.ms-excel` for xlsx files but the file does not want to open with Microsoft Excel. I added the Content-Type you suggested in the Uploader lambda (1st one listed above) and xls files worked.